# How to enable a disabled text-field with click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I have two text-field in Vuetify, I want that when I click on one of them, the other one is disabled, so far I have managed to make it happen, but, I want that when I click on the disabled one, the text is enabled and disabled again previous-field.
This is the code of the component:

```
      <v-row
        v-for="(f, index) in fieldsFilter"
        :key="index+'formfilterkey'"
        class="pa-0 ma-0"
      >
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="f.value"
              :label="f.label"
              :disabled="f.disabled"
              v-on:click="f.onClick"
              readonly
              clearable
              dense
              v-bind="attrs"
              :rules="f.rule"
              outlined
              :required="f.required"
              class="mx-3"
              v-on="on"
            />
```

And the textfield properties are generated from another file.

```
    created() {
    this.fieldsFilterControl=[
        {
            type: "datepicker",
            label: "Range 1",
            value: null,
            range: true,
            menu: false,
            disabled: 0,                
            onClick: ()=> {
                
                this.fieldsFilterControl[1].disabled = true
                
            }
        },
        {
            type: "monthpicker",
            label: "Range 2",
            value: null,
            range: true,
            menu: false,
            disabled: false,
            onClick: ()=> {
                
                this.fieldsFilterControl[0].disabled = true
                
            }
        },
    ],
```

Comment: why have you tagged both vue2 and vue3?

Answer (score 2):

***Disabling a `control` also disables its `events` (it's by design).***

I have a question for you - *Does the `text-field` truly need to be disabled ?*

As user can edit one text field at a time and this is how it will work if you disabled as well (as per your requirement).

***Solution :*** You can add a toggle button against a disabled text field and on click of that button you can enable the specific text field and disable another one.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    fieldsFilter: [
        {
            type: "datepicker",
            label: "Range 1",
            value: null,
            range: true,
            menu: false,
            disabled: false
        },
        {
            type: "monthpicker",
            label: "Range 2",
            value: null,
            range: true,
            menu: false,
            disabled: false
        }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    onEnableDisable(index) {
      this.fieldsFilter.forEach((obj, i) => {
        obj.disabled = i === index ? false : true
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.10/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.10/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons"/>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <v-container class="grey lighten-5">
      <v-row v-for="(f, index) in fieldsFilter"
             :key="index"
             class="pa-0 ma-0">
        <v-col sm="4">
          <v-text-field
                        v-model="f.value"
                        :label="f.label"
                        :disabled="f.disabled"
                        v-on:click="onEnableDisable(index)"
                        outlined
                        />
        </v-col>
        <v-col>
          <v-btn v-if="f.disabled" @click="onEnableDisable(index)">Enable Me</v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </template>
</div>
```